# How to diagnose and repair this NTFS volume

Tags: windows, ntfs, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption, storage-spaces

I have a Windows Storage Space that is an 8-drive array configured for parity and formatted as NTFS. Yesterday I was performing maintenance on some files using the security tab from the properties dialog of a folder to modify a large number of files recursively. No other process was working with this disk.

At some point the process locked up on a file and I requested the operation to cancel. A warning was provided that this would leave permissions in an inconsistent state but I decided that I could correct any issues later. Explorer locked up and the volume became unresponsive. I attempted to shut down the computer which resulting in Windows locking up so I powered it off forcefully.

Upon rebooting I had a number of issues mounting the affected partition. All other partitions have no issue.

Information of note:

Storage Spaces recognizes the pool and identifies it and all drives it comprises as in an "OK" (healthy) state. I can successfully mount the troubled volume but any form of access causes the process to lock up until the entire pool goes offline.

For example, in `CMD`:

```
> dir \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf}\
The device is not ready.

> mountvol z: \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf}\
> dir z:
```

The prompt will lock up until the pool finally goes offline. The command prompt provides the error:

`The parameter is incorrect.`

Storage spaces reports and error state and the following status for the pool. All physical drives still report as "OK":

`Offline due to critical write failures; add drives`

And Event Viewer says the following:

> Event 140, Ntfs (Microsoft-WIndows-Ntfs) -- WARNING
>
> The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur in VolumeId: Z:, DeviceName: \Device\HarddiskVolume78. (A device which does not exist was specified.)
>
> Error 0xc000000e

and

> Event 50, NTFS -- WARNING {Delayed Write Failed}
>
> Windows was unable to save all the data for the file . The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file elsewhere.

Attempting to perform a `chkdsk` on the volume or any mount point for it causes the same lockup with the same event warnings and the pool goes offline.

Because the pool would always go offline as a result of a write error I was able to recover the data by mounting the volume as read-only:

```
> diskpart
DISKPART> list disk
DISKPART> select disk 13
DISKPART> attributes disk set readonly
```

The disk was put back online :

```
DISKPART> online disk
```

And the volume was mounted:

```
DISKPART> select volume 2
DISKPART> assign letter z
```

Access to all files was restored and a backup was made.

Now that I've gotten all of my data back I'm left with a lot of questions. Firstly, I don't even know what went wrong or why the volume is so messed up.

I get no errors from `chkdsk`:

```
> chkdsk z:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Development.

WARNING!  /F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  526336 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  0 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  6 reparse records processed.
  627238 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
  6 reparse records processed.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  50451 data files processed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 134218748 KB total disk space.
  48483444 KB in 475729 files.
     61908 KB in 50453 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   2175476 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  83497920 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  33554687 total allocation units on disk.
  20874480 allocation units available on disk.
```

This is all I can do as any attempt to touch the volume when it's not write-protected causes the process doing so lock up and the pool to eventually go offline.

```
> chkdsk z: /r
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.

> chkdsk z: /f
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.

> chkdsk z: /scan
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Shadow copying the specified volume is not supported.

A snapshot error occured while scanning this drive. Run an offline scan and fix.

> chkdsk z: /offlinescanandfix
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Windows cannot run disk checking on this volume because it is write protected.
```

The volume also is not reported as "dirty":

```
> chkntfs z:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Z: is not dirty.
```

I still don't know what's wrong or what happened. The volume is still bad. I could delete it and start over but I don't know what the problem is. I think it's just software and something wrong with the filesystem but that's just a guess.

Any thoughts on how to diagnose this further or how to repair the volume if possible?

**UPDATE**

I set the disk as read-write but the volume as read-only. Then when attempting to check the disk it is reported as RAW instead of NTFS:

```
> chkntfs \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf}
The type of the file system is RAW.
Cannot query state of drive \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf}

> chkdsk \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf}
The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

If I mount it and then check it then it's recognized properly (still as read-only):

```
> mountvol z: \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf}

> chkntfs \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf}
The type of the file system is NTFS.
\\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf} is not dirty.
```

Mounted again as read-write on the volume but it locks up even when attempting to perform an offline scan:

```
> chkdsk \\?\Volume{73ad1258-809b-4db1-a153-9832c3697fcf} /offlinescanandfix
Cannot open volume for direct access.
```

(The pool went offline)